# How to reduce code repetition: TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have just started using the `TextInputLayout` to enable floating hints in android. Here's how I do it:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_password"
    style="@style/TextInputLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/line1">

    <EditText
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

The problem arises here. I have to write the same `TextInputLayout` for all my `EditText` fields. I have a signup activity with 7 fields. Is there a way to implement the `TextInputLayout` to all the EditTexts in one go? Or will I have to write it seven times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either you have to manage all things from your **`Java`** file or you have to put it 7 times in XML.

If you have different attribute values like `inputType` or `hint` then it will be better to use in **XML** or you have to manage that all things in **Java**

> Note: If you have same type of all `TextInputLayout` then you can
>   create one common **XML** for it and use `<include>` to include in you
>   main xml.

Thank you.